# Linear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the linear second order equation

$$ x^2U_{xx} −y^2U_{yy} =0 \qquad\qquad (14)$$

in the region $V =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :x>0,y>0\}$.

(a) Determine the type of the above equation in region V.

(b) Reduce equation (14) to the corresponding canonical form by making a suitable change of independent variables.

(c) Obtain the general solution of equation (14).

$U_{xx}$ is the second derivative of function $U$ with respect to $x$.

Hi above is a linear partial differential problem I have to solve, I really don’t know how to approach it. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Perform the change of variable
\begin{align}
\zeta &= \frac{x}{y} \\
\eta &= xy
\end{align}

Comment: kevin my solution is u(x,y)=f(x/y)+g(xy), does this sound correct to you?